# Error in the back end services in express.js

Tags: express

What is the error of these two code segments given below. when i tried this in school i didn't get errors,but in my personal machine i get some errors when i trying to run this methods.

/CONTROLLER CLASS

//update

```
 this.update = (id, data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.update({_id: id}, data).then(() => {
                resolve({status: 200, message: "update user"});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }
```

//DELETE

```
  this.delete = (id) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.remove({_id:id}).then(() => {
                resolve({status: 200, message: "remove user"});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message:"Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }
```

//routes class
//update

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Controller.update(req.params.id, req.body).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    })
});
```

//delete

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Controller.delete(req.params.id).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    })
})
```

Comment: Please share the error messages in your question.

Comment: Even we do see the error messages ... seems that this is not really related to the code itself (looks good) ... you are sure, mongo db is up and running and configured correctly?